# Why does this c++ code print out length 5 and when i'm print out string the program is automatic terminate?

Tags: c++, string

```
char start = 'a';
string out=""+start;
cout<<out.length()<<endl;
```

First we take a character in start variable then we take make string and initialize with start variable and print it ?

Comment: Please, note: `std::string out = std::string("") + start;` would work. ([**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/efa41fe0c88a5cf2)) For `std::string`, the `operator+` is overloaded to allow this. (For string literals, it cannot be overloaded.)

Comment: It will never cease to frustrate me how a language that is often annoyingly-strong  typed has more issues with unexpected implicit conversions than many more loose languages...

Comment: @AlexGeorg Compatibility to C... Most of these issues are derived from there. Suppose if Linus had written C++ without any of this in mind, quite some stuff would look differently today (maybe `&` operator would even have higher precedence than `==`, as we already have `&&` with lower precedence – haven't ever seen a use case for & without needing the parentheses around: `(a & b) == c`...

Comment: @AlexGeorg thanks to proper explain the string constructor working .

Answer (score 7):

```cpp
string out = "" + start;
```

This addition doesn't do what you think you do, `'a'` is being cast to an `int` according to it's ASCI value, you're moving the pointer by that many elements, and then you're constructing the string from the `const char*` that you're passing, which causes UB, as it points to some invalid memory location that you're trying to read.

Answer (score 4):

`""` is a `const char[1]` (holding`'\0'`).

You are trying to add `'a'` to this - so it decays into a pointer whose adress than gets increased by `97` (`(int)'a'` == `97`). Now you assign the `std::string` to this out-of-bounds adress - which is undefined behavior.

---

to achieve what you want, you can use the [`operator""s`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s) to turn the `const char[1]` into an `std::string`. Then `std::string::operator+` will execute and correctly concatenate everything.

```
using namespace std::string_literals;

char start = 'a';
std::string out = ""s + start;
std::cout << "string: " << out << " - length: " << out.length() << std::endl;
```

output:

> string: a - length: 1

Comment: vote for using `using namespace std::string_literals` rest is just repeating older answer.

Comment: Thanks @Stack Danny, You are saying correct .The additional operator is increment the string address and the next string present in program after the increment is print.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the char to string and it works ->

```
char start = 'a';
std::string s(1, start);
std::cout << s.length() << endl;
```